# open same project in both webstorm and intellij and prevent asking "project file changed" window

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I want to get rid of the annoying popup window when opening the same project in both webstorm and intellij. This window constains

```
Project components were changed externally and cannot be reloaded:
RunManager
editorHistoryManager
ToolWindowManager
ProjectRootManager
ChangeListManager
FileEditorManager
Would you like to reload project?
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to open the same project in WebStorm and IntelliJ IDEA at the same time?

Comment: Lena's answer below is correct, you should probably mark it as such.  As annoying as it is, it's really the best solution. You simply go to file-> new project -> empty project and create it. Then you go to settings -> project -> directories -> add source and add the directory your source code is in. Then remove the empty project source directory and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have this problem but do *not* have WebStorm installed, strictly IntelliJ. Why do I get this error each time I use `git checkout develop` ... or any other branch? Every time!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that WebStorm and Idea use the same project format (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/project.html#d1374457e109),  but have different module types, settings, etc. So, it's strongly recommended to avoid sharing the project settings (.idea) between WebStorm and Idea.

If you like to proceed with working on your project in both IDEs, I can  suggest creating a separate project to be used in WebStorm: create a new  empty WebStorm project anywhere and then add a folder where your  javascript, HTML, etc. files are stored as an additional content root to  it using Settings/Project/Directories, Add content root.

Comment: as annoying as this is, it's really the best solution.  You simply go to file->new project -> empty project and create it.  Then you go to settings -> project -> directories -> add source and add the directory your source code is in.  Then remove the empty project source directory and you should be good to go.